# Cannot get related items with PnPjs search on workflow task content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, pnp, pnpjs

I am working on SPFx Project and using PnPjs search. My requirement is to search for pending workflow task for that I have created **result source** at site collection level. Builder query as below

```
{searchTerms} ContentTypeId:0x0108* Path:{SiteCollection.URL} WorkflowOutcomeOWSTEXT:Pending
```

Now I am using SPFx to retrieve data. I cannot get related item of the task or related item id for the original item. Other than that I get all data. Let me know I am doing wrong or there is some issue pnpjs

My code as below (SPFx v2.0.6 and SharePoint Online/2019)

```
const getContentTypeData = async (rowLimit: number, sourceId: string, querytext: string, selectedProperties: string[]) => {
    const appSearchSettings: ISearchQuery = {
        RowLimit: rowLimit,
        EnableInterleaving: true,
        SourceId: sourceId,
        TrimDuplicates: false,
        Querytext: querytext,
        SelectProperties: selectedProperties
    }
    const searchResults: SearchResults = await sp.search(appSearchSettings)
    return searchResults
}
const selectedProperties = ['ListItemID', 'Path', 'Title', 'HitHighlightedSummary', 'LastModifiedTime', 'ParentLink', 'RelatedItems']
const rowLimit = 10
let queryText = `AssignedTo:"${displayName}"` // Passing current user displayName
getContentTypeData(rowLimit, searchSourceId.PendingTask, queryText, selectedProperties)
                    .then((r: SearchResults) => {
                        setPendingTask({ totalRows: r.TotalRows, primarySearchResults: r.PrimarySearchResults })
                    })
                    .catch(console.warn)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Milind,

Selected Properties should be managed properties and their retrievable flag should be true.

> Check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#selectproperties

By default "RelatedItems" is not a managed property, hence I'd like to suggest you map it to a managed property.

[image]

After that start a crawl to make sure the property has been crawled.

By the way, pnpjs indeed call sharepoint rest api to search items, so you can try below endpoint to have a fast test.

> GET http:// *server*/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&selectproperties='Title,RelatedItems'

[image: > Blockquote]

BR

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your solutions looks promising but I could not create Managed property for Related Item as I could find in Add Mapping.